# Sending mail using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have developed one application for **sending mail** using vb.net. for that i'm using system.net.mail namespace; but while sending mail i got one error that is **time out**. 
& for avoiding this error i used try catch block but i'm failed to resolve this problem.

Is there any solution on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem with the SMTP server, please verify your SMTP settings are valid and also verify firewall settings.

Comment: is there any another solution regardless this to resolve this error?

Comment: I don't know. Normally it would happen if you have some problem with SMTP server / server settings.

Answer (score 0):

you need open in windows firewall setting I think. What OS you used?if server need this. another I not try yet :D